# I need to find out how to add images to the pip installer library that I use for the background and icons of the program

Tags: python, tkinter, python-packaging, python-importlib

In order to use the image, I use the following commands

```
bg = Photo Image(file = "DNA.png")
label1 = Label(window, image = bg)
label1.place(x = 0, y = 0)
window.iconbitmap('DNAChain.ico')
```

And everything works fine until I make it out of it.exe file via pip
In the program, I use 2 images, one for the background and the second for the program icon, using pip to create a program.exe

```
D:\Python>pyinstaller --noconsole project.py --icon=D:\Python\NA Chai.icon
```

After creating it, I get the following error when running it

I'm a beginner, so I didn't come up with anything smarter than just transferring files to the dist or build folders[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn1S6.png)

Comment: "I compile in .exe the program through pip installer," - this description does not make any sense. Pip doesn't do any such thing. Please read [ask] and [mre] and make sure (by trying it yourself before posting) that someone else could **copy and paste** the code out of the question **without adding or changing anything**, follow your exact steps for whatever tools you are using (i.e.: show us what commands you are typing in the terminal, by **copying and pasting** them and formatting them like code), and see the **exact problem, directly**.

Comment: If you mean that you used PyInstaller, that is **completely unrelated** to Pip.

Comment: Make sure the files (images) are installed as part of the importable package, and then use `importlib.resources` to locate the files once installed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Take a look on the PyInstaller official document on [Runtime Information](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html) .

Answer (score 0):

If it cannot find the image, then the image is not in the same root folder as its being told it is in your code. So unless you have a typo, the solution would be to have a root folder 'Project' a folder in the root folder 'dist' containing the image and then your 'Project.py' in that root folder as a sibling of the 'dist' folder. Also, I would recommend separating images and fonts into a different folder named 'assets' for the sake of organization instead of having it all in one dist folder.